# How to block administrative user from accessing the internet on windows 7?

Tags: internet-explorer, window

How to force the administrative user to type in a password in order to open and use internet explore in windows 7?

Or

Uninstall or disable internet explore?

Comment: I have never heard of a feature nor a third-party software that would require a password to launch an application let alone limit it to IE.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound I clean-installed windows with dual boot linux. I want to prevent others and myself from opening internet explore, to reduce the chances of downloading malicious software on the computer.

Comment: Depending on your version of Windows (7 onwards I think)(and the other version - Professional, Ultimate etc.) you could try AppLocker - a Windows feature for restricting access to applications...

Comment: If you are worried about malware disable internet access entirely.  Furthermore you are worried about IE but what about other browsers.  Firefox and Chrome have the same risks to download malware.

Comment: @Ramhound I setup my windows to be a gaming platform for steam windows games. Steam and other game management software require periodic updates from the internet. In order to install new games on steam online, their must be an internet connection. I am not sure what is the best way or easiest to limit the user, without limiting programs that need internet.

Comment: Other than locking out the other users, or unplugging the computer, use good "paid for" antivirus and malware protection. Enable "real time" protection and run frequent scans. If you (they) are going to be on the Internet, expect issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB I could use antivirus, but my experience, that only delays the inevitable. Also running antivirus in the background starts slow down the system for gaming. Ironically, the system right now is super perfect, as long as NO HUMAN gets on the internet.

Comment: @linuxfreebird - Delete the shortcut.  I have had the same installation for 7 years across two machines, not a single virus, its not hard to keep your system clean.  In my experience IE11 is more secure then Firefox and Chrome anyways.

Comment: Going online to the Internet without protection is foolishness and you get what you get. If you choose to run without it, you can't blame other users who go online. Infections can come from all types of places. Like @Ramhound, I spend an enormous amount of time online and don't have issues. But I use protection.

Comment: @What do you recommend for protection software?

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Rather than asking about what you think the solution is, ask about your real problem instead. There's plenty of advice on how to secure Windows, and requiring an admin password for IE is surely not the way to go.

Comment: @slhck I disagree with the xy problem. Disabling user access to internet is the best solution. It eliminates almost all potential problems that can arise. The only way to get a virus is to pre-install software from another computer and load it into the windows computer.

Comment: I think this question can be easily answered in linux?

Comment: Wait can you uninstall internet explore or disable it? I thought that could not be done in windows, because other programs required it?

Comment: It *is* an XY problem. Your real problem is that you want to be safe  against malware under Windows. That's the ultimate goal, right? You think the solution is to disable access to IE, which is *not* a viable solution -- the actual solution is to protect the computer with a firewall, a virus scanner, and (most importantly) not downloading anything sketchy. See also: http://superuser.com/questions/565013/how-do-i-uninstall-internet-explorer-from-windows

Comment: @slhck I disagree with the viable solutions. Firewalls, virus scanners will only delay the inevitable. I think my firewall is active, but I will go back in check next time. The antivirus solution is an equivalent to cutting the buds off of a tree, disabling user internet access is cutting the problem at its root or source. By they way that was a really quick action to put this question on hold after I posted my response to your previous post.

Comment: If completely removing IE is a solution for you, then see the duplicate question. This still doesn't stop a user from downloading and installing browsers (or even malware) through the command line or third-party infected software (e.g. from USB drives). Honestly, you could probably lock IE with a password but it doesn't achieve what you want for all purposes of security. "Internet access" is not the same as "IE access".

Comment: @slhck Thanks for mentioning about internet access through the command line. I totally forgot about that. This makes this problem highly nontrivial and difficult.